# Python mock doesn't work

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

I need to write a test, there is `StringIO` and `curl`, so I tried to mock them but it returns bad data, not same as I waiting for.

Python test function:

```
def test_make_curl_request(self):
        redirect_url = 'abc'
        content = 'Content'
        mock_curl = mock.MagicMock()
        mock_curl.getinfo = mock.Mock(return_value=redirect_url)
        mock_curl.setopt = mock.Mock()
        mock_curl.perform = mock.Mock()

        mock_io_string = mock.MagicMock()
        mock_io_string.getvalue = mock.Mock(return_value=content)

        with mock.patch('pycurl.Curl', mock.Mock(return_value=mock_curl)):
            with mock.patch('source.lib.StringIO', mock.Mock(return_value=mock_io_string)):
                with mock.patch('source.lib.to_str', mock.Mock(return_value=redirect_url)):
                    with mock.patch('source.lib.to_unicode', mock.Mock(return_value=redirect_url)):
                        with mock.patch('source.lib.prepare_url', mock.Mock()):
                            self.assertEqual(init.make_pycurl_request('http://test.rg', 10), (content, redirect_url))
```

Testing function:

```
def make_pycurl_request(url, timeout, useragent=None):
    prepared_url = to_str(prepare_url(url), 'ignore')
    buff = StringIO()
    curl = pycurl.Curl()
    curl.setopt(curl.URL, prepared_url)
    if useragent:
        curl.setopt(curl.USERAGENT, useragent)
    curl.setopt(curl.WRITEDATA, buff)
    curl.setopt(curl.FOLLOWLOCATION, False)
    # curl.setopt(curl.CONNECTTIMEOUT, timeout)
    curl.setopt(curl.TIMEOUT, timeout)
    curl.perform()
    content = buff.getvalue()
    redirect_url = curl.getinfo(curl.REDIRECT_URL)
    curl.close()
    if redirect_url is not None:
        redirect_url = to_unicode(redirect_url, 'ignore')
    return content, redirect_url
```

So my mock on `content` doesn't work, I don't really know what to do.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're creating more mock objects than you need and you're not setting return values quite right. For instance,  I'd replace `mock_io_string.getvalue = mock.Mock(return_value=content)` with `mock_io_string.getvalue.return_value = content`.